# pm2 nodejs getting dropped connections to database in cluster mode -i 2

Tags: node.js, docker, cluster-computing, pm2

I am noticing something strange and I am not sure how to debug this.

I am encountering a problem where when i run pm2 in cluster mode with -i 2, i get a lot of dropped connections when i do queries to my database but when i have -i 1, i don't get dropped connections

i am using keymetrics/pm2:8-alpine in my dockerfile and my command looks like this

```
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "server.js", "-i","1"]
```

my vm has two cores

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED but when i try the same query again it works. it seems like for a brief moment there were no connections in the pool available to serve the query

Comment: sorry the logs  dont say much, im using the knex module in nodejs and i turned on debug but all it says is Error: connect ECONNREFUSED  or ECONNRESET. im guessing this is some sort of connection pooling problem